# Retrieving the column next to the first occurrence of a match

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set like this

```
ID  Manager1_id   manager1_company  Manager2_id  Manager2_company  Manager3_id  Manager3_company...M9id M9C

1    100           ABC                   101       XYZ                102             ABC          104 DEF
2    200           XYZ                   201       xyz                202             ABC          204 ABC
3    300           DEF                   301       DEF                302             XYZ          304 XYZ
4    400           DEF                   401       ABC                402             DEF          404 XYZ
```

and so on till `9 manger id` and `manger 9` company

So I need to find first occurrence of `XYZ` and retrieve the `Manager ID` of the first occurrence of `XYZ`

**Example 1**:  For `ID 1`, `XYZ` occurs in `manager2` company so I need to retrieve `101` (Manager1 ID) as a new field.

**Example 2**:  For `ID 2`, `XYZ` occurs in `manager1`, `manager 2` but I need just first occurrence only and that particular manager id into a new column

Can we do this in Excel or in VBA?

Comment: Since you asked for VBA, [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination.

```
=INDEX(B2:I2,,MATCH("XYZ",B2:I2,0)-1)
```

[image]